# How to fix LookDev mode grey screen

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, gpu

I'm having a problem with Blender after a recent GPU crash. While rendering a moderately intense scene in Cycles, my computer locked up and I had to do a hard shut-down. Ever since, Blender's LookDev mode has only shown me a grey screen. I can 'see' the edges of my plane, but no other details, no textures or materials. Lighting does not work at all for me in this mode. Eevee also does the same thing in either LookDev or Render modes, with even more broken results sometimes in the form of reflective artifacts.

I have tried importing my scene into a new file. I updated to a newer version of Blender, and I also re-installed my graphics drivers. None of these gave any improvements. I am at a loss and a bit of a wall, as I am having a hard time working on my file without LookDev mode. Any and all help is appriciated.

Scene shown in Solid View mode with random colors.
[image: Scene shown in Solid View mode with random colors.]

Scene shown in LookDev mode, grey screen with some edges barely visible.
[image: Scene shown in LookDev mode, grey screen with some edges barely visible.]

Comment: If you have an AMD card, the latest Adrenalin drivers are likely the issue. Try rolling back to a previous version.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Please click on "Close > Duplicate" and paste the link to our favorite AMD question so it gets into the [review queue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review). Can be re-opened anytime, so nothing to loose here but would save some time.

Comment: @brockmann If you frequent the review queues, you'll know I do that all the time. - Guess I missed one.

Comment: I don't mind and it is *your* spare time. Just saying that the last time you voted to close a question was in July: https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/75504/christopher-bennett?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=7 @ChristopherBennett

Comment: That's absolutely not true. I voted to close at least three questions related to the exact same  question as recently as yesterday. I don't know where you're getting you're info, but I'd check again if I were you. - https://ibb.co/RjHrV1k

Comment: Yep It's bah humbug season. Voting to close via close link on  question, and +1 voting to close via the review queue is misunderstanding  here.   Other users cannot see your voting page.  (screenshot)  IMO it would be preferable  to add a vote to close re AMD driver case rather than  a comment.... or worse  as an answer.   The dupe link is easily found ...  it's currently never too far  from the top of the close vote review queue history page https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/close/history   _Gray or Grey  spelling doesn't help either_  The more closed the better the matching. hopefully

Comment: @ChristopherBennett No reason to check again I trust you, and again it's *your time* and decision, easy. batFINGER is right, what I mean is that it would help us if you would click the close button below the question, not the one in the review because you are one of those guys here having enough rep and experience to do that. Cheers!

Comment: I **AM** clicking the close button below the question - each and every time - I don't understand why this is such an issue..... Half my time on this site these days is voting to close dupes related to AMD GPU issues. I even have the link to the correct question copied elsewhere for quick access. All I do is close, close, close, and now I'm being _told_ to close? This makes no sense...